# Rails 6.1.5: uninitialized constant Mail::TestMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Why am i getting 'uninitialized constant Mail::TestMailer' error with "Rails 6.1.5 & Ruby 3.1.0" while working without problems "Rails 6.1.5 & Ruby 3.0.1" ?

Comment: think you should move your answer to the answers :) you can self-answer questions :)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found following from [NEWS for Ruby 3.1.0](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_1_0/NEWS.md).

```
The following default gems are now bundled gems.

net-ftp 0.1.3
net-imap 0.2.2
net-pop 0.1.1
net-smtp 0.3.1
matrix 0.4.2
prime 0.1.2
debug 1.4.0
```

So, i just added next 3 lines into GemFile. It worked fine.

```
gem 'net-smtp' # to send email
gem 'net-imap' # for rspec
gem 'net-pop'  # for rspec
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, after debugging and troubleshooting. I made changes to the Rails version to 6.1.1.4 instead of 6.1.7. The I got similar error stating that it could not load some .rb files from the mail gem.
What I did was to give them the read permission to others.

```
chmod 644 <ruby-file-in-mail-gem>.rb
```

and the application loaded fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same issue after deploying the code on server.
Version details-

```
Rails 6.1.5
ruby 3.1.2p20
```

I just install a new gem as-

```
gem 'net-smtp'
```

and issue got resolved.